# Doctrine Entity setter doesn't work

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a weird bug, when I do `getUser()`, it returns null.

This is my code :

```
 $connectionToken->setToken($hashToken);
 $connectionToken->setCreationDate($date);
 dump($userID); // 30 
 $connectionToken->setUser($userID);
 $connectionToken->getUser()
 dump($connectionToken->getUser());// null
```

An this is a part of my ConnectionToken class :

```
/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="user", type="string", length=255)
 */
private $user;

/**
 * Set user
 *
 * @param string $user
 * @return ConnectionToken
 */
public function setUser($user)
{
    $this->$user = $user;
    dump($this->$user); // 30 
    return $this;
}

/**
 * Get $user
 *
 * @return string
 */
public function getUser()
{
    return $this->user;
}
```

Have you got an idea what could be the problem ?

Comment: I wouldn't tag this neither Symfony2 nor Doctrine2. This looks like raw PHP and it doesn't really make sense. Are you sure you are looking to the correct "dump" or maybe you have other "dumps" going on? Also since you like debugging this way, why don't you try putting a `die()` after each one to see where exactly you are in the code?

Comment: @ggioffreda Yep agree with you, doesn't make any sense. I am into this bug since five hours ... All the dump belongs here. And I have a php error when I do my persist($entity) saying that user is null. And if I put basic dump like dump('setter here') they are where they should be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just a typo in your `setUser` function:

`$this->$user` has to be `$this->user`